# Calculating how many rows until condition met?

Tags: r, tidyverse, cumsum, recode

I am trying to create a new column that shows me how many rows UNTIL a condition is met in a row. That is, for each row, how many times will a nation see FALSE before they get to a TRUE

```
data <- data.frame(year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014), 
                   nation = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "BEL", "BEL", "BEL", "BEL", "BEL", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "MEX", "MEX", "MEX", "MEX", "MEX"), 
                   approved = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

Using this dataset, I need a fourth column that will tell me how many years each nation will have a FALSE until they get a TRUE. For instance, the first row shows 2010 USA TRUE. How can I get a fourth column that shows that there will be 3 FALSE before another TRUE?

I am very new to this, so I am not even sure where to start. I have considered some cumsum() functions but I can't figure out how to get my number to count down rather that add up, if that makes sense.

Hopefully, I can get something that looks like this:

```
nation  approved years_until
USA TRUE    3
USA FALSE   2
USA FALSE   1
USA FALSE   0
USA TRUE    NA
UK  TRUE    0
UK  TRUE    2
UK  FALSE   1
UK  FALSE   0
UK  TRUE    NA
BEL FALSE   1
BEL FALSE   0
BEL TRUE    0
BEL TRUE    0
BEL TRUE    NA
AUS FALSE   0
AUS TRUE    0
AUS TRUE    0
AUS TRUE    0
AUS TRUE    NA
MEX TRUE    0
MEX TRUE    2
MEX FALSE   1
MEX FALSE   0
MEX TRUE    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more concise way, but here's the first approach that came to mind. For each nation, look at it in reverse and make a group for each period that leads up to a TRUE in `approved`. Then the `years_until` is the `row_number()` in that group, less 1.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(nation) %>%
  arrange(nation, -year) %>%
  mutate(true_grp = cumsum(approved)) %>%
  group_by(nation, true_grp) %>%
  mutate(years_until = row_number() - 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(nation, year)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 25 × 5
    year nation approved true_grp years_until
   <dbl> <chr>  <lgl>       <int>       <dbl>
 1  2010 AUS    FALSE           4           1
 2  2011 AUS    TRUE            4           0
 3  2012 AUS    TRUE            3           0
 4  2013 AUS    TRUE            2           0
 5  2014 AUS    TRUE            1           0
 6  2010 BEL    FALSE           3           2
 7  2011 BEL    FALSE           3           1
 8  2012 BEL    TRUE            3           0
 9  2013 BEL    TRUE            2           0
10  2014 BEL    TRUE            1           0
# … with 15 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thank you Jon! I think this gets me most of the way there, but there is one change that I think needs to be made. I need the years_until to begin it's count AFTER the row. I.e., I need it to not count the FALSE in its own row year (if that makes sense). So from your result you can see for 2010 BEL and 2011 BEL we have 2, 1, & then 0 because it meets a true. I need it to be 2010 BEL 1 because there is only one more FALSE between that row and the row with a TRUE. I know this is probably confusing and I am not sure if I'm explaining correctly. I think I can do this with a lead() but I'm not sure

Comment: Maybe `years_until = pmax(0,row_number() - 2)` might suffice?